# Android Device install new font

Tags: android

I need to install Tamil font in to my Android device. is it possible to install new Unicode font in to the android device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can embed your own fonts in your own applications for their own use. You cannot add fonts to an existing device, except as part of a custom firmware build, or possibly by rooting the device.

Comment: "You can embed your own fonts in your own applications for their own use" means can I use a font in my application which is not supported by the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but as Tamil is not supported as Unicode support is not there in Android.
You will have to make changes as system level and then flash your new system image.

Thanks,
Shaista