# How to install custom font in android device

Tags: android

I want to install custom font which is  .ttf file in android device when my application start. Actually I need to install Burmese font in my android device when I run my application. Is it possible? If yes, then how? I don't need typeface. I want to install in system.

Answer (score 21):

See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421741/android-device-install-new-font) @CommonsWare  answer, You cannot add fonts to an existing device, except as part of a custom firmware build, or possibly by rooting the device.

but you can add fonts in your appliction. like:

```
 TextView txtvw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewname);

 Typeface typface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/burmese.ttf");

  txtvw.setTypeface(typface);
```

**Note:** put your font in `assets/fonts` dir in project

**OR** if your device is rooted then see this tuts for installing [Custom Fonts on Your Android Device](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/install-custom-fonts-on-android.580313/)

Comment: +1 for rply fast. Thanks for your reply i see this and also other links like http://www.android-devs.com/?p=33 http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/productivity/gurmukhi-keyboard_rppe.html         but is it possible to all device rooted.

Comment: @khushi : this app installing fonts on all unrooted  devices?

Comment: probably should be another question but if several fragments/etc execute the same code to "createFromAsset" does it smartly access a font cache or does it create another instance each time?  ie: do I need to manage it application wide and only use one instance to save memory?

Comment: Hi, I am using LG G4 with Android 6.0 and I want to add a new font to Word. My phone is not rooted.  How Can I do it? I don't understand the codes above and how to apply it....

Answer (score 4):

you need to be on root of the device

for that you can use this application EasyRoot.apk

Download and install ES File Explorer
(https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)

After that you need to enable root explorer.
More info can obtained from this link

http://chetangole.com/blog/2011/08/enabling-installing-hindi-marathi-unicode-fonts-on-android-mobile/

save  fonts on your device’s /system/font folder

More info can obtained from this link

http://chetangole.com/blog/2011/08/enabling-installing-hindi-marathi-unicode-fonts-on-android-mobile/

Answer (score 3):

if you have custom font then use following code:::

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Verdana.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

also place your font in assets/fonts folder

Comment: hi don't want to typeface i mentioned. i want to install in system.

Answer (score 0):

I created a FontWrapper Class for my project.

```
public static Typeface getTypeface(Context c, Fonts name) {

        synchronized (typefaces) {

            if (!typefaces.containsKey(name)) {

                try {
                    String fontPath = getFontsPath(name);

                    if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(fontPath)) {
                        InputStream inputStream = c.getAssets().open(fontPath);
                        File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);
                        if (file == null) {
                            return Typeface.DEFAULT;
                        }
                        Typeface t = Typeface.createFromFile(file);
                        typefaces.put(name, t);
                    } else {
                        return Typeface.DEFAULT;
                    }

                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Typeface.DEFAULT;
                }
            }
            return typefaces.get(name);
        }
    }

private static File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

        try {
            File f = File.createTempFile("font", null);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            return f;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: From Android O onwards you can specify fonts directly in XML : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Comment: This question is asking about a system font, not using typeface.