# How does android decide which font to use?

Tags: android, fonts

I am showing a list of languages to select for the user. I am running on Android 4.1.1 and on a rooted device.

```
<string name="g_lang_English">English</string>
<string name="g_lang_Bahasa">Bahasa</string>
<string name="g_lang_Tamil">தமிழ்</string>
<string name="g_lang_Bengali">বাংলা</string>
<string name="g_lang_Chinese">华语</string>
<string name="g_lang_Vietnamese">Việt</string>
<string name="g_lang_Thailand">ภาษาไทย</string>        
<string name="g_lang_Khmer">ភាសាខ្មែរ</string>
```

All the languages are shown correctly except for Khmer (Last one). It's empty. This is because by default Khmer font is not installed I assume.

So then I tried and manually set the type face for each TextView using

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile("/sdcard/Smart Unicode Body Regular.ttf"));
```

which worked just as I wanted. However I was surprised that it worked for all the other fonts and not Khmer so I pushed the font I used to to `/system/fonts`. But still it doesn't work if I don't manually set the typeface using Java.

How does Android decide which installed font to use to display the text in the TextView ?
What should I do to configure Android to display Khmer without having to manually set the font using `setTypeface` ?

Comment: You might have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051915/how-to-install-custom-font-in-android-device