# Telugu font in nokia x

Tags: fonts, nokiax

I bought a new Nokia-X mobile, but it doesn't support Telugu font.

Is there any procedure to add/install Telugu for to Nokia-x mobile.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively the device is Android phone, thus I would recommend following instructions for normal android devices.

For example check the [How to install custom font in android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051915/how-to-install-custom-font-in-android-device) for more information.